# Django custom management command to populate a many to many table

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I am learning python and Django. I loaded a pretty big amount of data from csv files to my database. One of the csv files is describing a many to many relation.

```py
# models.py
class Provider:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    product = models.ManyToManyField("Product", related_name="vendor_products")

class Product:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

The generated database tables are `core_provider`, `core_product` and `core_provider_product`.

I already have the data for the `core_provider_product`

```
| provider_id | product_id |
|-------------|------------|
| 3           | 1001       |
| 1           | 1003       |
| 3           | 1007       |
| 2           | 1001       |
| 1           | 1002       |
| 1           | 1001       |
# etc
```

and I am feeding them to the database with this custom management command:

```py
class Command(BaseCommand):
    # add_arguments snip

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for file in options["csvfile"]:
            with open(file) as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                    for row in reader:
                        myprovider = row[0]
                        myprovider_obj = Provider.objects.get(pk=myprovider)
                        myproduct = row[1]
                        myproduct_obj = Product.objects.get(pk=myproduct)
                        myprovider_obj.product.add(myproduct_obj)
```

which works fine. (takes about 6 mins to complete for a ~6000 lines file)

But it feels terribly sloppy and inefficient. What is a better way to do this? I suspect Django already has a way to achieve this, but my search skills fail me and I cannot figure how to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) command to upload a .json file from the shell:

```
python3 manage.py loaddata /your_project_path/dummydata.json
```

Not sure about the performance compared to your current method, but 6 minutes sounds awfully long to dump 6k object to the database.

One way to generate the `.json` file is to take a dump from you database `after` you have populated the database using your current method. To this end, you can use the [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) command:

```
python3 manage.py dumpdata > dummydata.json
```

The resulting `.json` format should automatically be in the right format as expected by the `loaddata` command